# Trouble decrypting an AES key with RSA private key

Tags: python, encryption, key, aes, rsa

I have a AES key that has been encrypted with a RSA public key. I need to decrypt it with a list of RSA private keys. Having issues with the packages I'm using to get the RSA key to decrypt the AES key.
Stuck on what I should be using.

```py
for pKey in os.listdir(pathPK):
    os.chdir(pathPK)
    if pKey.startswith("private"):
        privateKey = PKCS1_OAEP.new(open(pKey, 'r').read())
        for aKey in os.listdir(pathAK):
            os.chdir(pathAK)
            akiv = 
            aesKey = AES.new(open(aKey, 'r').read(), AES.MODE_CBC, 32)
            decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(aesKey)
```

I have updated the post and now get this as an output at the moment:

```
ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (256 bytes)
```

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: `aesKey = open(aKey)` What does this do?

Comment: I am assuming it  opens the aes file in the path i have. I've been trying different solutions and have added .read() to it